# count aggregation on jsondata->field using django ORM query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a model like

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
class data(model):
     content=JSONField()
     .......
```

My sample DB entry for the model data would be

```
data1   : id =1, content = {"email":"abc@gmail.com"}
data2   : id =2, content = {"email":"cdf@gmail.com"}
data3   : id =3,  content ={"email":"abc@gmail.com"}
data4   : id = 4, content ={"email":"sfg@gmail.com"}
data5   : id = 5, content ={"email":"abc@gmail.com"}
data6   : id = 6, content ={"email":"sfg@gmail.com"}
```

I need to get find the non-unique "email" values and list of ids like

```
"abc@gmail.com"  :  [1,3,5]
"sfg@gmail.com   :  [4,6]
```

I'm using django 1.11 and python 2.7 and postgres9.3

My query was

```
lists = data.objects.filter(....).extra(select={'email':"content->>'email'"}).values('email','id')
```

the results i got is

```
{"email":"abc@gmail.com","id":1}
{"email":"cdf@gmail.com","id":2}
{"email":"abc@gmail.com","id":3}
{"email":"sfg@gmail.com","id":4}
{"email":"abc@gmail.com","id":5}
{"email":"sfg@gmail.com","id":6}
```

Which includes unique and non-unique values, which is not what is required.

**Query 1:** Is there a possibility to query only unique values from JSON field using Django.

Tried `distinct()`  but it fails as both 'id' and 'email' in in the values part

anyhow processed it further as

```
for d in lists:
    if d['email'] not in temp:
        temp[d['email']]=[d['id']]
    else:
        temp[d['email']].append(d['id'])
```

Got results as all values including unique and non-unique as below

```
"abc@gmail.com"  :  [1,3,5]
"sfg@gmail.com"  :  [4,6]
"cdf@gmail.com"  :  [2] ## not desired
```

**Query2:** Is there any way that would process this data more efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

For **postgresql** and **django >= 1.9** you can try [ArrayAgg](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/aggregates/#arrayagg). Your query could be like this

```
lists = data.objects.filter(....).extra(select={'email':"content->>'email'"}).values('email','id').aggregate(list=ArrayAgg('id'))
```

Comment: data.objects.filter(...).extra(select={'email':"content->>email"}).values('email').aggregate(list=ArrayAgg('id'))   This one gives the answer correctly

Comment: This one was the most perfect result   data.objects.filter(...).extra(select={'email':"content->>'email' " }).values('email').annotate(Count('id')).filter(id__count__gt = 1).annotate(list=ArrayAgg('id'))